# Slow user logins after configuring Windows Server 2003 as VPN Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, vpn

I have a Windows Server 2003 box setup as the Domain Controller for a Windows Domain Network.  It has 2 NICs one of which is currently unused.  I've followed the configuration instructions detailed by a number of sources:

- [How to install and configure a Virtual Private Network server in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323441)
- [Configure a Windows Server 2003 VPN on the server side](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5805260.html)

However, every time I add another role to the server to function as a VPN server, user logins take minutes to authenticate with the domain.  In addition,the VPN connection works but DNS lookups fail when connected over VPN an an IP address must be used to resolve to individual boxes.  I'm sure I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what that is.

---

Answer (score 1):

First, admittedly, I have not done anything like your setup.  That being said, it sounds like you have some name resolver issues that are the root of the problem.  AD needs to have a healthy DNS setup to function properly, and the long delays may be attributed to attempts to contact a FSMO role - which requires a DNS lookup - and as a result, a DNS timeout occurs, which then rolls into another resolver address.  Eventually it figures out everything, although I just can't shake the suspicion that if you check the network adapter's DNS settings, they're pointing at something that won't answer DNS queries.  You might also want to check any DNS settings on the VPN adapter (if applicable - remember, I haven't tried anything like this, I use [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) instead...)